# Maven install-file confusion: "could not find goal 'install-file'"

Tags: maven

This error looks like nonsense: Could not find goal '**install-‌​file**' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2 among available goals install, help, **install-file**

The command I'm entering is:

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-‌​file -Dfile=mypackage.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Arg! I copy/pasted that command from elsewhere on StackOverflow and the hyphen-dash in `install-file` had been replaced by a similar looking character.

After manually replacing the hyphen-dash, the command worked fine.